# Responsive cycle2

Tags: window, width, jquery-cycle2

have the following code

```
$('.carousel').cycle({
fx: 'carousel',
slides: 'div',
carouselFluid: true,
speed:1000,
timeout:3000,
pauseOnHover: true,
next: '.next',
prev: '.prev',
swipe: true,
carouselVisible:4
});
```

how to make a number of carouselVisible depending on the width of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @user3351668 Im working on the same thing myself.
I think the following might be useful...

https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/68